# Woocommerce - exclude only older out-of-stock items

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, pre-get-posts

Trying to find a way to exclude out of stock items from listing, but only after some time (let's say, if they're older than one month).

I know I can exclude all of them easily, or change the order using something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/219349/4741), but I'm looking for a something in-between... I guess using a `pre_get_posts` hook, but not sure about the specific query.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most information necessary can be found at the [Code Reference: `WP_Query` | Class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) . Otherwise useful resource [Theme Handbook: Conditional Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/). Below code contains some clarifying comments. Please note, this is untested code, so no guarantees, but it should get you going.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_woocommerce_product_query' );
function custom_woocommerce_product_query( $q ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() ) {   
    //query for the out of stock items we want to exclude
    $oos_query = new WP_Query( [ 
      // items must be older than 1 month
      'date_query' => [ [ 
        'column' => 'post_date', 
        'before' => '1 month ago' 
      ], ],
      //only out of stock items...
      'meta_query' => [ [ 
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => '=',
       ], ],
      //we want products, nothing else
      'post_type' => 'product',
      //we want them all
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      //the ids are enough, no need to get more data 
      'fields' => 'ids',
    ] );
    //getting array of ids from object
    $exclude_ids = $oos_query->posts;

    //excluding the above queried products from woocommerce's product query
    $q->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolai! query seems to work well and update the exclude ids correctly. Somehow the items are still displayed on the category listing... Not entirely sure why. I'm still in the process of debugging it. The code is executed, and I can see excluded post ids, but some of those excluded ids are still listed... :(

Comment: @YoavAner Thanks for fixing the error in the code. After peaking quickly into the source [`class-wc-query.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-query.php), I realized most conditionals aren't necessary, so I removed them. Maybe this resolves your issues, not 100% sure. According to the source code: »_// Only apply to product categories, the product post archive, the shop page, product tags, and product attribute taxonomies._«, this is where we hook in, so I think it should target category listings too. Keep me posted.

Comment: Nicolai thanks again. I realize it's nearly impossible to debug things over SO comments :) I don't think those conditions were the problem. The code was executed, and the `post__not_in` was set with the right ids on the query, but somehow the category page was still showing them... I'll have to spend more time debugging I guess. In any case I'll accept the answer, because it definitely seems like the right thing to do, just not sure why it's not fully working for me.

Comment: I think my problem was some weird caching issue or something. It does seem to work! One small thing however: the item counts for each category aren't affected by this update to the query, so it shows a higher count than what's actually displayed... Maybe there's a different hook to update the query on? I'll try to search and update if I find anything.